# SQL select command returns unreadable ascii characters

Tags: sql, sqlite, terminal, ascii

When I run the following command in sqlite3

```
.mode ascii
SELECT * FROM tablename;
```

The return string look like this [image]

I believe these weird symbols are suppose to represent integers but are in an ascii string form.

This happens in other modes (ex. `.mode tab` make newlines have weird characters)

Is it my terminal that can't read ascii or sql that isn't working? How can I fix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `ascii` mode then. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @CL. a course at Udacity requires the output in ascii mode to pass the quiz. I guess I'll just have to skip that quiz. Thanks.

Comment: "ASCII mode" probably means just plain text (i.e., `.mode list` or `.mode csv`) and not a screen shot like in your question. Anyway, if they really want these ASCII control characters, it does not matter how they are displayed in *your* terminal.

Comment: @CL. Thank you that's the solution. If you want to write an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: The same Udacity quiz brought me here, haha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are non-printing characters for columns and your terminal does not know how to interpret them.

Comment: I don't know of any terminal that understands these ASCII control characters.